# Uncaught ReferenceError: currentSlide is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, функции

Я сделал горизонтальный слайдер и по аналогии решил сделать вертикальный. Но я столкнулся с проблемой, связанной с функцией. Переменные назначены, индексы доступны, но тем не менее пишет, что функция не определена.

Кнопки «dots2» должны отвечать за переключение слайдера, а также за функции стрелок. Но если со стрелками проблем не было, то эта проблема происходит с кнопками.

```js
let strip = document.getElementById('strip2');
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('slider-top').onclick = slidertop;
  document.getElementById('slider-bottom').onclick = sliderbottom;
  document.getElementsByClassName('dots2').onclick = currentSlide2;
  let top = 0;

  function slidertop() {
    top = top - 305;
    if (top < -915) {
      top = 0;
    }
    strip.style.top = top + 'px';
  }

  function sliderbottom() {
    top = top + 305;
    if (top > 0) {
      top = -610;
    }
    strip.style.top = top + 'px';
  }
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  let slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function currentSlide(n) {
    alert(top);
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    if (n == 1) {
      top = 0;
    }
    if (n == 2) {
      top = -305;
    }
    if (n == 3) {
      top = -610;
    }
    if (n == 4) {
      top = -915;
    }
    strip.style.top = top + 'px';
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    let i;
    let slideIndex = 1;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("switch1");
    let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots2");
    if (n == 1) {
      top = 0;
    }
    if (n == 2) {
      top = -305;
    }
    if (n == 3) {
      top = -610;
    }
    if (n == 4) {
      top = -915;
    }
    /*for(let i=0;i<slides.length; i++){
      slides[i].style.display="none";
    }*/
    for (let i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      /*dots[i].className= dots[i].className.replace("","active");*/
      /*slides[i].style.display = "block";*/
      /*dots[i].className+="active";*/
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#slider2 {
  width: 372px;
  height: 901px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-left: 323px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*
  Элементы не вылазят над бордер*/
}

#slider2 img {
  width: 372px;
  height: 291px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

#strip2 img:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#strip2 {
  height: 1816px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  /*Чтоб не было рывка при первом нажатии кнопки*/
  transition: all ease 1s;
  /*Скорость прокрутки*/
}

#strip2::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#buttons2 {
  margin-top: 51px;
  margin-left: 836px;
}

.slider-dots2 {
  margin-top: 53px;
  margin-left: 897px;
}

.dots2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0 16px;
  background-color: #F8F6FB;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: #4D4E90;
  border: 1px solid #4A5193;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.activedots2 {
  background-color: #564A84;
}

.dots2:hover {
  background-color: #564A84;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider2">
  <div id="strip2" class="mySlides2">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_1" alt="slide 1" class="switch1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_2" alt="slide 1" class="switch1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_3" alt="slide 1" class="switch1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_4" alt="slide 1" class="switch1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_5" alt="slide 1" class="switch1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_6" alt="slide 1" class="switch1">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="buttons2">
  <button class="slider-button" id="slider-bottom"><img id="arrow-left" src="images/Arrow-left.png"/></button>
  <button class="slider-button" id="slider-top"><img id="arrow-right" src="images/Arrow-right.png"/></button>
</div>
<div class="slider-dots2">
  <span class="dots2" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dots2" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dots2" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dots2" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
</div>
```

Я пытался бросить функцию в onload, переназначить переменные и многое другое

Comment: У вас функция `currentSlide` определена в обработчике `onload`. Она не видна глобально, поэтому не работает.

Comment: У вас на самом деле много ошибок. `document.getElementsByClassName('dots2').onclick` - работать не будет. `let top = 0;` - не самое удачное имя для глобальной переменной.

Comment: Дело в том что 'currentSlide' не работает даже будучи оглашенной глобально, а переменная названа топ, чтоб посредством добавления +'px', оказать влияние на стиль отображения.

Comment: Я вам говорю про одно, а вы совсем про другое. `document.getElementsByClassName('dots2')` возвращает коллекцию. У коллекции нету события `onclick`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я исправил ваши ошибки, надеюсь, вы разберетесь, что к чему.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  initSlider();
}

function initSlider() {
  let strip = document.getElementById('strip2');
  let top = 0;
  document.getElementById('slider-top').onclick = slidertop;
  document.getElementById('slider-bottom').onclick = sliderbottom;
  [...document.getElementsByClassName('dots2')].forEach((f, i) => f.onclick = () => currentSlide(i + 1));


  function slidertop() {
    top = top - 305;
    if (top < -915) {
      top = 0;
    }
    strip.style.top = top + 'px';
  }

  function sliderbottom() {
    top = top + 305;
    if (top > 0) {
      top = -610;
    }
    strip.style.top = top + 'px';
  }
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  let slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function currentSlide(n) {
    alert(top);
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    if (n == 1) {
      top = 0;
    }
    if (n == 2) {
      top = -305;
    }
    if (n == 3) {
      top = -610;
    }
    if (n == 4) {
      top = -915;
    }
    strip.style.top = top + 'px';
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    let i;
    let slideIndex = 1;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("switch1");
    let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots2");
    if (n == 1) {
      top = 0;
    }
    if (n == 2) {
      top = -305;
    }
    if (n == 3) {
      top = -610;
    }
    if (n == 4) {
      top = -915;
    }
    /*for(let i=0;i<slides.length; i++){
      slides[i].style.display="none";
    }*/
    for (let i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      /*dots[i].className= dots[i].className.replace("","active");*/
      /*slides[i].style.display = "block";*/
      /*dots[i].className+="active";*/
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#slider2 {
  width: 372px;
  height: 901px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-left: 323px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*
  Элементы не вылазят над бордер*/
}

#slider2 img {
  width: 372px;
  height: 291px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

#strip2 img:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#strip2 {
  height: 1816px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  /*Чтоб не было рывка при первом нажатии кнопки*/
  transition: all ease 1s;
  /*Скорость прокрутки*/
}

#strip2::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#buttons2 {
  margin-top: 51px;
  margin-left: 836px;
}

.slider-dots2 {
  margin-top: 53px;
  margin-left: 897px;
}

.dots2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0 16px;
  background-color: #F8F6FB;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: #4D4E90;
  border: 1px solid #4A5193;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.activedots2 {
  background-color: #564A84;
}

.dots2:hover {
  background-color: #564A84;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider2">
  <div id="strip2" class="mySlides2">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_1" alt="slide 1" class="switch1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_2" alt="slide 1" class="switch1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_3" alt="slide 1" class="switch1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_4" alt="slide 1" class="switch1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_5" alt="slide 1" class="switch1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_6" alt="slide 1" class="switch1">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="buttons2">
  <button class="slider-button" id="slider-bottom"><img id="arrow-left" src="images/Arrow-left.png"/></button>
  <button class="slider-button" id="slider-top"><img id="arrow-right" src="images/Arrow-right.png"/></button>
</div>
<div class="slider-dots2">
  <span class="dots2"></span>
  <span class="dots2"></span>
  <span class="dots2"></span>
  <span class="dots2"></span>
</div>
```